# MKMapVIew Rounded Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I would like to know if is there anyway that I can make a MapView a circle, I tried using, mapView.layer.cornerRadius, but it didn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try putting it into a container view, and change that view's cornerRadius instead.

Comment: ... making sure it's configured to clip subviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember to set the `masksToBounds` property of the layer to `YES`, in addition to setting a corner radius.

Comment: The corner radius is changing, but it doesn't make a circle

Comment: @Skal What value did you set it to? It should be half of the map view size.

Comment: The size is 272 x 154, what radius should I use?

Comment: If you want a circle, it needs to be a square size.